# Autolayout: Specify spacing between view and navigation bar

Tags: ios, autolayout

I'm trying to figure out what constraints I should set to place view below navigation bar. The problem is that its height depends on current orientation (44 in portrait, 32 in landscape), so I can't use the exact number.

[image: portrait]  [image: landscape]

Is there any special value I can use for the constraint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using top and bottom layout guides to create constraints would probably be the correct solution, but they are available only in Storyboard mode.

In case they are not available (or don't work for some reason), solution is the following:

1. Create constraint relative to superview top (actual value doesn't matter at this point, we will set it in code).
2. Create outlet for constraint from step 1 (the same way you would for a view).
3. Modify your view controller code:

```
 
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    //initial setup
    UIInterfaceOrientation currentOrientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;
    [self applyTopBarOffsetForOrientation:currentOrientation];
}

- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    [super willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation duration:duration];
    [self applyTopBarOffsetForOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation];
}

- (void)applyTopBarOffsetForOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation) orientation {
    BOOL isPhone = [UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone;
    self.topBarSpacingConstraint.constant = UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation) && isPhone ? 52 : 64;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[image: Constraints]

See that top constraint that is highlighted?  That will let you set a fixed distance to a neighboring view.  The problem is that your navigation bar is likely on top of the embedded view which means you need to uncheck the "Under Top Bars" setting and then you will be able to set a constraint to the top layout manager.

[image]

Comment: I assume "Extend Edges" section is only available in Storyboard mode, because I can't seem to locate it in simple Xib editor.

Comment: Anyway, what do I do if I want to have my background under navigation bar? How do I specify spacing in this case?

Comment: It should be in the XIB file as well but its a part of the controller, not the view and most people only bother with adding controllers if they are using Storyboards.  You can do it programatically though as `UIViewController` has a `topLayoutGuide` property and then just set the auto layout distance to the top of the view in the XIB file.

Comment: thanks for the pointer. I'll try that as soon as I figure out how to specify constraints programmatically.

Comment: Hmmmm...in that case you might need something like this: BOOL isLandscape()
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]);
}

Comment: Good luck.  There might be ways to adjust the top layout guide without affecting the whole view but I think you might be better off at that point just creating a utility function like the above and/or overriding the method `- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration` in `UIViewController`.  Not the most elegant solution but it will get the job done.

Comment: Try setting your distance to the top layout guide to -66 to be flush with the top of of the status bar.  I believe -46 would be flush with its bottom edge.

Answer (score 1):

This is precisely why iOS 7 provides the `Top Layout Guide` and `Bottom Layout Guide`  Create your restraint relative to them and the right thing will happen.

Comment: Is the top layout guide supported when the edges extend under the navbar?  I notice that the layout guide is only displayed as an object in IB Autolayout when that is turned off...is it just assuming the layout guide and the frame edge are the same?

Comment: If edges extend under the bars, then yes, the frame edge and layout guide are the same.